# google sheets script get cell contents

Tags: json, parsing, spreadsheet

I have a list of URLs in a google spreadhseet and I want to get the cell reference to be used as a URL in the script.

An example of a URL I will be getting data from: https://politicsandwar.com/api/nation/id=31831

[image: List of URLs]

I want to do something like getValue.("O2") or var urlData = "O2" but I don't know how to go about getting to that point.

Answer (score 1):

You should first get a range and then get its values.

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

//Gets all cell values form column "O" starting from row 2. Returns a 2d array
var wholeColumnUrls = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("O2:O").getValues();

//Gets value from specific cell "O2".
var singleCellUrl = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("O2").getValue();
```

There are [multiple](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow-column) [ways](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow-column-numrows) of [defining a range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow-column-numrows-numcolumns), in this example we use the [A1notation variant](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation). Which seems to be what you're looking for.

Also, notice the difference between [`getValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) and [`getValue()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue). The first returns a 2d array like:

```
[
    [https://politicsandwar.com/api/nation/id=31831]
    ,[https://politicsandwar.com/api/nation/id=31832]
    ,[https://politicsandwar.com/api/nation/id=31833]
]
```

while the latter returns a single value like `https://politicsandwar.com/api/nation/id=31831`

That way you can choose wether you get all the values and iterate over them, or have your own logic to determine each cell and get the values separately.